# Catching a param from URL by using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, parameters

I have a constant link looking like this:

```
http://link.com/?val1=val1&val2=val2
```

And this link redirects me to a new link with a random value of a constant param such like;

```
http://link2.com/?constant=randomvalue/
```

Each time I use the first link, I get a random value from the following link.

By using Node.js, how can I catch the 'randomvalue' of 'constant' in the second link?

**I have to use the first link to reach the second one.**

Answer (score 1):

Try reading the second link as a URL

```
let secondURL = new URL("http://link2.com/?constant=randomvalue/");
```

Then extract the value of the `constant` searchparam like so

```
let constantValue = secondURL.searchParams.get("constant"); //"randomvalue/"
```

Comment: But I have to use the first link to reach the second one, so directly reaching the second link won't make any sense because the random value will stay same.

Comment: Then you should probably update your question with an example of what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

@Misantorp's answer is probably best, but there is another way to do it. Check out the querystring module built into Node, it has a convenient parse method just for things like this: https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html

This should work:

```
const querystring = require('querystring');

querystring.parse("http://link2.com/?constant=randomvalue/"); // { 'http://link2.com/?constant': 'randomvalue/' }
```

You may want to substring from the `?` onwards to make it more clear:

```
const str = "http://link2.com/?constant=randomvalue/";
const paramIndex = str.indexOf("?");
if (paramIndex >= 0) {
    const queryParamStr = str.substr(str.indexOf("?"));
    const queryParams = querystring.parse(queryParamStr);
    console.log(queryParams["constant"]);
}
```